# Rails and sidekiq : is it possible to assign a name to a job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

With Ruby-on-Rails, is it possible to assign a name to a sidekiq job, and make this name appears in the /sidekiq web console or other debugging possibilities ?

Comment: you see the worker class and job parameters, is that not sufficient?

Comment: indeed, job's parameters appears for a scheduled job. But is there a way to display also for the processed jobs ?

Comment: Processed? The ones that were done? Sidekiq does not store any info on those (except incrementing the counter)

Comment: Display what, specifically? You could create a model and persist information there. But, depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I created a model `JobLogs` and use the callbacks of ActionJob to log some of my jobs for debugging. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq 6.0.1 added support for job tags.

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options tags: ['bank-ops', 'alpha']
  ...
end
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#601